# .Bottom is read-only

Tags: winforms, powershell, listbox, resize

I'm working on a PowerShell script that uses forms and panels that are docked. I was able to create the form and panels just fine, but I'm having issues getting a listbox to resize during runtime using `$inputbox.Bottom = $form.Height - 215` to control the size, but I recieve the error

> 'Bottom' is a read-only property.

Simply using `Fill` in the panel will not work because I have buttons above and below the listbox. Here is a sample of my code:

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.Windows.Forms”)
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.Drawing”)

$form.ResizeEnd
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1040,459)
$form.KeyPreview = $true
$form.StartPosition = ‘centerscreen’
$form.BackColor = 'MidnightBlue'
$form.Add_KeyDown({if($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape"){$form.Close()}})
$form.Text = "Dialog Box 2.0" 
$form.Icon = [system.drawing.icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($PSHOME + "\powershell_ise.exe")

$buttonPanel3 = New-Object Windows.Forms.Panel
$buttonPanel3.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(290,70)
$buttonPanel3.Dock = "left"
$buttonPanel3.BackColor = 'Blue'

$inputbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$inputbox.BorderStyle = 'NONE'
$inputbox.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font(“segoe UI”,9)
$inputbox.SelectionMode = "MultiExtended"
$inputbox.Left = 10
$inputbox.Top = 105
$inputbox.Width = 200
$inputbox.Bottom = $form.Height -215
$inputbox.Height = $form.Height -215

$buttonPanel3.Controls.Add($inputbox)
$form.Controls.Add($buttonPanel3)
$form.ShowDialog()
```

If someone could give some sample code of a listbox that resizes (mainly concerned with vertical expansion) when you resize the form that would be excellent.

Comment: Edit the `Height` property, not the `Bottom` property

Comment: When I edit the height property it will initialize right, but it won't modify while the program is running.

Comment: Are you attempting to do it manually (ie. by dragging the borders of the control)? I don't see any attempts to programmatically resize any controls *while* the form is shown

Comment: Please give an example of how to do that.

Comment: How to do *what*? Are you looking for a user-resizable listbox control, or an example of how to resize the control programmatically?

Comment: What I would like to do is when the user drags the corner of the form down the listbox expands vertically to match. The listbox is attached to a panel with other buttons above and below it also attached to the panel. How to resize the listbox during runtime as I stated in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up completely rearranging my form and using the fill method, but I wanted to put in a tidbit about form resizing since that was the true issue here.

The resize handler for the form would be `$form.Add_Resize({})`. Inside the brackets I could modify the height and width properties as desired. In this case, I only wanted the height property, so the code would be like:

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.Windows.Forms”)
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.Drawing”)

$form.ResizeEnd
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1040,459)
$form.KeyPreview = $true
$form.StartPosition = ‘centerscreen’
$form.BackColor = 'MidnightBlue'
$form.Add_KeyDown({if($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape"){$form.Close()}})
$form.Text = "Dialog Box 2.0" 
$form.Icon = [system.drawing.icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($PSHOME + "\powershell_ise.exe")
$form.Add_Resize({
    $inputbox.Height = $form.Height -215
})

$buttonPanel3 = New-Object Windows.Forms.Panel
$buttonPanel3.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(290,70)
$buttonPanel3.Dock = "left"
$buttonPanel3.BackColor = 'Blue'

$inputbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$inputbox.BorderStyle = 'NONE'
$inputbox.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font(“segoe UI”,9)
$inputbox.SelectionMode = "MultiExtended"
$inputbox.Left = 10
$inputbox.Top = 105
$inputbox.Width = 200
$inputbox.Height = $form.Height -215

$buttonPanel3.Controls.Add($inputbox)
$form.Controls.Add($buttonPanel3)
$form.ShowDialog()
```